# Change button id back on unsuccessful form submit

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a rather simple form that contains an optional image upload field. Since uploading image data takes time, I would like for the form button (which by css, is displayed as a background image) to display an alternate image that lets the user know the form is in the process of submitting the data and at the same time, disable the button to prevent multiple clicks.

Here is the relevant part of the form:

```
<input name="formsubmit" type="submit" id="button" value="Submit!">
```

I have managed to piece together the following bit of jQuery:

```
jQuery('#formid').submit(function() {
     jQuery('#button').attr('id', 'button-post');
     jQuery('#button').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

This does exactly what I need. The problem is, I am using a jQuery inline validation plugin ([Link](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/)) and when you get to the form and submit the form without filling out any fields and click the submit button, the button id changes like I want but since the plugin I am using returns errors because the required fields are not filled out, the button id attribute won't change back to the original id.

Is there a way around this? Perhaps a way to check if the form was actually successfully submitted or maybe if one of the other required fields is over a certain length?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you changing the ID of the button - surely you just need to switch out a CSS class on it?

I guess you could check if the validation is successful, and submit the form if it is:

```
$("#button").click(function() 
{
     if your validation is OK
     {
        jQuery('#button').attr('id', 'button-post');       
         jQuery('#button').attr('disabled','disabled');
         document.forms["myform"].submit();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the first thing, IDs should change, that is a bad practice.  This is what class is used for.

But anyways, the workaround to you problem would involve actually handling the ajax request yourself.

```
jQuery('#formid').submit(function() {    
    var options = 
    {
        //Define ajax options
        url : '' //your http request target
        type: "post",
        target: "#responsePanel",
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            // button-disabled is a CSS class that would have your visual effects for the
            // changed button.
            jQuery('#button').addClass("button-disbaled").attr('disabled','disabled');
        },        
        success: function(response, statusString, xhr)
        {
            // process your response.
        },
        error: function(response, status, err)
        {
           //Handle your error here.
           jQuery('#button').removeClass("button-disbaled").attrRemove('disabled');
        }
     }
     $.ajax(options);
});
```

NOTE, code not tested, might be errors.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
jQuery('#formid').submit(function() {
  if ($("#formid").validationEngine('validate')) {
     jQuery('#button').attr('id', 'button-post');
     jQuery('#button').attr('disabled','disabled');
  }
});
```

This ensures that your validation passes before changing the state of the button.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it certainly was easy enough to implement. However, now the id of the button is not changing when the form is processing or when it successfully submits. The validation works fine and the button id does not change prematurely as it did before though. Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm still messing around with this. It seems like the line 'if ($("#formid").validationEngine('validate')) {' is not returning true like it should?

Comment: Not sure, I haven't looked at the validation engine in about a year, I just remember that it had a validate method that could be called like that. There might be some sort of callback you could attach to the validation engine itself instead, have you looked into that?